# c program how to print a char array held by a structure variable?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, char

How do I print the char array held in the struct variable `char binary_filename`?

I tried:

```
printf("Binary file name is : %s \n", prv_instance_t.binary_filename);
```

However, I get the error `error: expected expression before ‘prv_instance_t’`

Here is the struct definition.

```
#define BINARY_FILE_NAME_MAXLEN   10 

typedef struct _prv_instance_
{
    /*
     * The first two are mandatories and represent the pointer to the next instance and the ID of this one. The rest
     * is the instance scope user data (uint8_t power in this case)
     */
    struct _prv_instance_ * next;   // matches lwm2m_list_t::next
    uint16_t shortID;               // matches lwm2m_list_t::id
    uint8_t  power;
    uint8_t  reset;
    double   dec;
    char binary_filename[BINARY_FILE_NAME_MAXLEN];
} prv_instance_t;
```

Comment: You need a variable of type `prv_instance_t`, not the type itself.

Comment: @Mat **_"You need a variable of type prv_instance_t"_**. I think he needs prv_good_C_book_t

Comment: `prv_instance_t var; fgets(var.binary_filename, sizeof var.binary_filename, stdin); var.binary_filename[strcspn(var.binary_filename, "\n")]=0; printf("Binary file name is : %s \n", var.binary_filename);`

Comment: You should show the code where you initialize `binary_filename` before printing it.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the type itself. To access a member of the struct you have to declare an instance of that struct first. For example, [this will print](http://ideone.com/j816A0) `Hello World` :

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BINARY_FILE_NAME_MAXLEN 10

typedef struct _prv_instance_
{
    char binary_filename [BINARY_FILE_NAME_MAXLEN];
} prv_instance_t;


int main()
{
    prv_instance_t foo, bar;
    strcpy(foo.binary_filename, "Hello");
    strcpy(bar.binary_filename, "World");

    printf("%s %s\n", foo.binary_filename, bar.binary_filename);
    return 0;
}
```

What you are trying to do is similar to

```
printf("%d", int);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `typedef` keyword.

Current definition does not define a variable, but makes two equivalent types `prv_instance_t` and `struct _prv_instance_`. From your question I understand that `prv_instance_t` should be an instance (variable) of type `_prv_instance_`, keyword `typedef` is unnecessary.

Your `printf` will work with:

```cpp
#define BINARY_FILE_NAME_MAXLEN   10

struct _prv_instance_
{
    /*
    * The first two are mandatories and represent the pointer to the next instance and the ID of this one. The rest
    * is the instance scope user data (uint8_t power in this case)
    */
    struct _prv_instance_ * next;   // matches lwm2m_list_t::next
    uint16_t shortID;               // matches lwm2m_list_t::id
    uint8_t  power;
    uint8_t  reset;
    double   dec;
    char binary_filename[BINARY_FILE_NAME_MAXLEN];
} prv_instance_t;
```

as well as with the following one:

```cpp
#define BINARY_FILE_NAME_MAXLEN   10

struct _prv_instance_
{
    /*
    * The first two are mandatories and represent the pointer to the next instance and the ID of this one. The rest
    * is the instance scope user data (uint8_t power in this case)
    */
    struct _prv_instance_ * next;   // matches lwm2m_list_t::next
    uint16_t shortID;               // matches lwm2m_list_t::id
    uint8_t  power;
    uint8_t  reset;
    double   dec;
    char binary_filename[BINARY_FILE_NAME_MAXLEN];
};

struct _prv_instance_ prv_instance_t;
```

Comment: @Yunnosch Actually the first example looks like printing empty string, but question was about compilation error.

Comment: Once again for down-voters: 1) question was about compilation error; 2) prv_instance_t in the provided examples is global, so all its fields will be initialized with defoult values, that equals to `char binary_filename[BINARY_FILE_NAME_MAXLEN] = {0};`

Comment: @Yunnosch OK. I deleted parts that provoke senseless discussion

Comment: May I recommend to change phrasing to ".. that makes `prv_instance_t` *a variable of* a type similar to ..."? When first reading your interesting answer, this tripped me up and prevented me from immediatly understanding the mechanism.